# I get negative value while reversing the LinkedList

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I have a problem while I try to reverse a linked list. Numbers in the linked list are:

```
9, 0, 14, 7, 1
```

When I try to reverse them, I get:

```
7, 14, 0, 9, -842150451.
```

I'm wondering why I don't get the number **1**, but I get as output **-842150451**.

Here's my `displayinReverse()` method:

```
void LinkedList::displayinReverse() {
    if (first == NULL)
        return;
    Node *prev = NULL, *current = NULL, *next = NULL;
    current = first;
    while (current != NULL) {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    first = prev;
}
```

Invokation of `displayinReverse()` method:

```
    case 6:
        cout << "Elements reversed: ";
        myList.displayinReverse();
        myList.display();
        break;
```

Here is an image showing that reversing the list 1 time will not work but when I reverse it again I will get the original list:

[image: reverse the list 2 times]

Comment: Removed the C tag. Your code is C++, don't mistag. Also, C++ has a more type-safe approach to null pointer with `nullptr`. Use that instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Considering that it doesn't do any output, `displayinReverse()` is a rather strange name. Also, broken camelCasing.

Comment: Please provide a complete and verifiable example. Node definition is missing so as the display method

Comment: -842150451 is a magic value.  Convert it to hex (0xcdcdcdcd) and google that.

Comment: Your algorithm is a little complex.  Why not swap next & previous for each element and then point first to the 'last'?

Comment: Your algorithm looks fine and is the same as here: http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/reverse-a-linked-list/. There may is an other error.

Comment: @UKMonkey It's a singly-linked list, that's why the algorithm is more complex. Granted, this is somewhat hard to see from the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Potential areas where you might want to take a look:

1. Examine the code that pertains to how you are building your `Node` objects in your Node constructor methods or `createNode` method. Ensure you are `NULL` initializing the appropriate fields properly.
2. Initialization of the `first` global variable. Your output seems to indicate that you are starting off with `first` pointing to the 2nd element in the node (The output starts with `7` and not `1`).
3. Your `display()` method/function is very likely iterating beyond the  last element (the tail) in the list. The logic of `display()` method/function needs to be examined.

From the examination of your output, it seems like the cause of the bug might be in Step 2 and 3.